# Unable to calculate distance between patches when inside ask turtles

Tags: netlogo

Please help with the following code:

```
     ask turtles[
       ......
       let new-patches no-patches
       ask patch-here [ set new-patches neighbors]
       let new-patch min-one-of new-patches [distance goal-patch] 
       face new-patch
       .....
]
```

**Aim:**
I want the above code to make the turtle to face towards the patch which is nearest to  a given patch ("goal-patch").

**Obvious approach not followed:**
The reason I don't directly use facexy is that there are obstacles in between so the turtles get struck.

**Error:**

```
 let new-patch min-one-of new-patches [distance goal-patch]
```

this code can't be run by a patch
error while turtle 101 running DISTANCE

Comment: What is `goal-patch`? Is it a variable or procedure? If procedure, can we see the code? The code as shown should work, though it could be cleaned up. For instance, `neighbors` can be run by the turtle directly, so you dispense with the `new-patches` variable altogether. The code would then become `face min-one-of neighbors [ distance goal-patch ]`.

Comment: Agree with Bryan: the code you have shown us is correct.

Comment: goal-patch is patch the turtle has reach. My code still gives error I don't know why ,though I tried Bryan's code and it works well.  THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like goal-patch is probably a turtles-own'd variable.

In that case, the expression "distance goal-patch" is a turtles-only expression. It only has meaning to a turtle. So, a patch can't run it. In other words, the patch does not have access to any variables called "goal-patch".

You need to provide the value of goal-patch in a way that a patch can use. You can either use `[ goal-patch] of myself` or you can save the value of goal-patch in a temp variable.

However, this ignores the real problem with this code, is that you are trying to choose among the neighbor patches that are nearest the goal patch, and your code is very complicated for that.

See, turtles can use "neighbors" directly. So, if you want to find the neighbor patch nearest the patch contained in the turtles-own'd variable `goal-patch` (using distance), it is:

```
set nearest min-one-of neighbors [ distance ( [ goal-patch ] of myself ) ]
;; parenthesis added for emphasis
;; --distance can't be inside the brackets with goal-patch
```

In this context, `myself` refers to the turtle running this line of code. "Myself" is a tricky reporter, and understanding it is important to writing inter-agent interactions correctly.

Hope this helps.